# HTML5 change the RGB values of an image

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I'm new to image manipulation with HTML5. I need some help to change the RGB values of an image to create different effects. Around the web I didn't find any straight forward tutorial about it. I've put together a bit of code to start with taken here and there on the web:

```
 window.onload = function(){
     var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function(){
         drawImage(this);
     };
     imageObj.src = "images/test.jpg";
 };

 function drawImage(imageObj){
      var canvas = document.getElementById("mau");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      var destX = 1;
      var destY = 1;

      context.drawImage(imageObj, destX, destY);

      var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var data = imageData.data;

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
          var red = data[i]; // red
          var green = data[i + 1]; // green
          var blue = data[i + 2]; // blue
          // i+3 is alpha (the fourth element)
      }

      // overwrite original image
      context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
 }
```

At this stage the image is shown with no variation. How do I change the 3 variables R, G, B in order to enhance the blue channel for instance? And can someone please run me through the code to understand it better?

Thanks in advance
Mauro

Comment: You've not actually changed `imageData` at any point, you've just read the values into `red`, `green` and `blue` and then done nothing with them.

Comment: yes Robert that's the point of my question. I can read them but how do I change them?

Comment: The other way around: `data[i] = whatever`.

Comment: ok I've done this: data[i] = 23; 
                    data[i + 1] = 23; 
                    data[i + 2] = 120; but returns just a blue square with no image. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've set every pixel in the image to have a red value of 23, a green value of 23 and a blue value of 120 - you're doing everything right.

Comment: Ok thanks I've figured out! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/XbGf6/).  It swaps the red, green and blue components around:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      var red = data[i]; // red
      var green = data[i + 1]; // green
      var blue = data[i + 2]; // blue
      // i+3 is alpha (the fourth element)
      data[i] = green;
      data[i + 1] = blue;
      data[i + 2] = red;
  }
```

The original image is from Wikipedia:

[image: test image original]

Comment: The image doesn't load anymore

Comment: there is an image which reads "Please don't upload files with this title. Use a more precise name" in your answer. I don't think that this is what you meant to use as an example image.

Comment: and you don't intend to fix this?

Comment: to me it looks like an error-image which replaced the image you intended to use for your example.

Comment: really confusing choice, when you ask me.

Comment: what if you'd be needing to change between black&white

Answer (score 0):

I would try [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) library.

You could use the `ColorFilter`, `ColorMatrix` and `ColorMatrixFilter` to manipulate images. It's easy to alter the values, you can easily animate (transition) them, too.